# No asp.net features on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I thought I could see an ASP.NET features panel (I don't know the exact name, though, some of them are .Net Compilation, .Net Roles, .Net Users and so on) on the IIS7 manager when I click a site node in the nodes list of the IIS7 manager. Now, I can see only IIS and Management, but no ASP.NET.

I first installed .NET Framework 4.0, so after installing IIS7, I used the aspnet_regiis tool, and seemed it worked well.

My environment is
Windows 7 Pro
IIS 7.5.7600
.NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found the solution here.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1154433.aspx

- Open Control Panel
- Programs\Turn Windows Features on or off
- Internet Information Services
- World Wide Web Services
- Application development Features
- ASP.Net <-- check mark here

Andrew Zhu saved my life, thanks!

Comment: this give me ideas, i was using windows server 2008 so it had to be done using the role manager

Answer (score 18):

The solution that worked for me was slightly different:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Programs\Turn Windows Features on or off
3. Roles\Web server (IIS) Right-click Add Role Services Click on
   ASP.NET and allow it to add any others it suggests.
4. Click Next
5. Close and re-open IIS

Comment: This was a solution for me but I'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: erg.. re-open IIS.. just wasted 30 minutes not doing that... thanks