# No ASP.NET features shown in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I'm having an issue in IIS 7.5 where the ASP.NET feature section isn't showing on my web application.

My environment: Windows 2008 R2 SP1, IIS 7.5 (7.5.7600), .NET Framework 4.0

My issue is similar to the issue posted here: [No asp.net features on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234930/no-asp-net-features-on-iis-7-5), only my environment is different. The 'add features' fix mentioned in that post doesn't appear to work in Windows Server 2008, as I'm not seeing a simple "ASP.NET" feature that can be selected.

I tried running the aspnet_regiis tool as administrator against .NET 4.0 with no luck. The application pool selected for the web application is currently configured to use .NET 4.0. This application is functional, so I'm assuming that .NET 4.0 is installed correctly, but I'd like to be able to configure a few more things that are in the ASP.NET section.

Comment: Have you run `aspnet_regiis.exe` from the .NET 4.0 framework folder?

Comment: The ASP.Net feature set is under Internet Information Services > Word Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > ASP.NET

Comment: @StefanH This might be a stupid question, but how do I access that feature set. When selecting "Control Panel" -> "Turn Windows features on or off", it takes me to the Server Manager. Then when I select "Add Features" in Server Manager, I'm not seeing anything like "Internet Information Services" or "ASP.NET".

Comment: @Oded Yes, tried that, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try Roles > Right Click Web Server (IIS) > Add Role Services > Application Development...

Comment: @StefanH That's exactly what I needed! I ran that and the ASP.NET features now show. Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try Roles > Right Click Web Server (IIS) > Add Role Services > Application Development to turn on the ASP.Net features in IIS

Answer (score 19):

The UI is a bit different in the newer versions of Windows Server. Here is where you have to enable ASP.Net in order to get it working on IIS

[image: How To Fix IIS ASP.Net Errors]

Answer (score 2):

The same issue but in a developer machine it may solve:

`Windows Features - Internet Information Services - World Wide Web Services - Application Development Features - ASP.NET 3.5 + ASP.NET 4.8`

[image]