# Missing asp.net features on IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I'm using IIS 10.0 and  ASP.NET feature section isn't showing

My environment: Windows Server 2016

My issue is similar to the issue posted here: [No asp.net features on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234930/no-asp-net-features-on-iis-7-5) and [No ASP.NET features shown in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891089/no-asp-net-features-shown-in-iis-7-5)

The 'add features' fix mentioned in those posts doesn't apply as it was already correctly configured that (see image)

[image: windows server 2016 iis 10.0 missing asp.net section]

Comment: I have a similar issue. IIS10 on Win2019. ASP.NET section disappeared when I installed Web Deploy 3.6. I have uninstalled and reinstalled IIS, ASP.NET, and Web Deploy, nothing worked.

Answer (score 25):

From the Screenshots in the OPs questions I deduced that mine simply weren't selected in the server roles section of the server administrator. For clarity I added these:

```
"Add roles and features" 
    -> "Server Roles"     
       -> "Web Server (iis)" 
          -> "Web Server" 
             -> "Application Development" 
                -> "ASP.NET 4.6" (I also needed 3.5 for legacy reasons)
```

Then restart IIS manager (just close the window and reopen it)

Answer (score 3):

This section's appearance is also triggered by the application pool's .NET CLR version.

I encountered this when I added two copies of the same .NET 5 (Core) application to IIS. Each had their own app pool which used the "No Managed Code" .NET CLR version.
I was surprised to find that one had the ASP.NET section but the other didn't.

Turns out I had initially created one of the app pools with the default setting for .NET CLR version of V4.0. Even though I had corrected this it still showed the ASP.NET section for the corresponding application until I removed the application and added it back in.

Answer (score 1):

We applied updates to the server, rebooted and then this bug went away.  Magically the asp.net section appeared.

Comment: what updates did you specifically apply? can you be more specific?

Comment: It was just whatever update MS had submitted at that time.  (1 year and 5 months ago)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same scenario as the OP, but I hadn't restarted IIS manager. When I closed and reopened IIS, the ASP.NET section was present