# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - what is the cause?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have created an Angular2/.NETCore application in Visual Studio, which when debugged works fine.  I published this on my local IIS, and this also is running fine.  However when I moved everything to a remote server, I got the following error:-

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
```

I checked that I have the correct permissions on the remote IIS, however I cannot understand why I am getting this error.

I already tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208209/iis-8-0-asp-net-and-error-500-19)

but no luck so far.

Anyone has any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: source of error can be not changed DataSourceString or give permissions virtual directory to default user.

Comment: When you open a terminal at the location of your web app and type `dotnet the.app.dll`, does this report an error?

Comment: @VinuthaN sorry did not understand you

Comment: @MartinUllrich I opened a command prompt at the location of the application (ex c:\myapp) and I got "The application to execute does not exists"

Comment: and is there a `dotnet.exe` (=> dotnet installation directory) on the system's `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: yes Martin when I do donet --help, I get the help, which means that its installed correctly right?

Comment: Have you install [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) on remote server?

Comment: how do I know if that is installed?  Let me try to install it

Comment: That Server hosting bundle did eventually work Martin!  How can I add this as the answer?  Maybe it will help others

Comment: Added as answer @Johann, Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the **.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle** on the hosting system. The bundle will install the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the **ASP.NET Core Module**.

For more information refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle).