# Deploy ASP.NET MVC3 project on IIS7 in local network

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, webserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS2010 error: Unable to start debugging on the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878136/vs2010-error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server)

I wrote an ASP.NET MVC3 project with Visual Studio 2010. I want to deploy it on IIS7 web server in my local network. I instlled IIS7 successfully. In Visual Studio, project menu,  Properties... , choose Use Local IIS Web server but I can't run project and this window appears:

[image]

Can anybody tell me whats wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply start Visual Studio as Administrator!

Comment: I started it as administrator, but doesn't work

Comment: You may be required to change web.config manually. Set <compilation debug="true" /> and compile the project in Debug mode.

Comment: compilation debug was true in default. When I run project in Debug mode I see described window but when I run it without debugging browser shows root directory of project.

Comment: Can't help you further, without more detailed information. Try Google! There are really many websites about the problem and also very similar questions with comprehensive answers on stackoverflow: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878136/vs2010-error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server).